# ERROR at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored; Error(2,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having this error on oracle SQL developer

```
create table loan_audit (
employee_id number not null,
tool_no number not null,
tool_out_date date not null,
due_date date not null);
```

This is the trigger i created

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER loan_audit_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON loan_02
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit VALUES
    (:new.employee_id, :new.tool_no, :new.tool_out_date, :new.due_date, 'INSERTED', SYSDATE);
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit VALUES
    (:old.employee_id,  :old.tool_no,  :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date, 'UPDATED', SYSDATE);
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit VALUES
    (:old.employee_id,  :old.tool_no, :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date, 'DELETED', SYSDATE);
  END IF;  
END;
```

I am getting these error

```
Error(2,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(2,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
Error(5,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
Error(8,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(8,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
```

what am i doing wrong? I been trying to get this to work but keep getting this error! Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Your table has 4 columns, but you are trying to insert 5 values, so Oracle complains `too many vaues`. As a side note, a recomended way is to explicitely list column names in the insert statement - `INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, ... colN) VALUES( val1, val2, ... valN)`. Using INSERT without listing column names is considered as a bad practice, since it may cause a lot of errors.

Comment: One of developer's job is to debug error.  The error message is very clear, "too many values".  It should give you clues that you have too many values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the columns explicit in any `insert`:

```
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (employee_id, tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
        VALUES ( :new.tool_no, :new.tool_out_date, :new.due_date );
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (employee_id, tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
       VALUES (  :old.tool_no,  :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date );
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (employee_id, tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
        VALUES (  :old.tool_no, :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date );
  END IF;
```

Oh, look.  The table has four columns, but you are inserting 5.  You need to decide if you want four or five and declare the table appropriately.

It also looks like you don't have an `employee_id` . . . perhaps you intend:

```
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
        VALUES ( :new.tool_no, :new.tool_out_date, :new.due_date, 'INSERTED', SYSDATE);
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
       VALUES (  :old.tool_no,  :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date, 'UPDATED', SYSDATE);
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO loan_audit (tool_no, tool_out_date, due_date)
        VALUES (  :old.tool_no, :old.tool_out_date, :old.due_date, 'DELETED', SYSDATE);
  END IF;
```